# rsync : how much time rsync takes to build file list before starting sync process b/w source & destination

Tags: backup, ubuntu-16.04, rsync

I am using rsync from more than 1 year to sync production data to an folder on the nfs volume, once sync completed our NDMP backup / Tape backup schedule will start.

Situation:
  Yesterday we observed that the rsync was still in process to sync file from production folder to destination folder, before completion of rsync command tape backup process was completed. Hence the tape backup data is inconsistent.

Question 1) how to find how much time rsync took to generate list of files which needs to be synchronized b/w source & destination folder?

I used below command to print the time stamp to identify how much time rsync took to generate file list before copying file process start.

rsync -avz --out-format="%t %f" --delete /opt/app_home/shared/data /opt/app_home/shared/plugins /opt/app_home/shared/tape-backup-rsync-shared_new/

However seeking guidance on how to determine the time taken at each stages of rsync process so that i can tweek my scheduled cron job execution times.

Answer (score 0):

Relying on timing is probably a poor idea because it will vary according to how much data needs to be moved, and how congested the machine and/or network might be. I suggest you either make your schedule very generous, or else implement some kind of locking mechanism.

Try this for your rsync:

```
flock /path/to/some/nfs/filename.lock rsync <args>
```

And this for your tape backup:

```
flock /path/to/some/nfs/filename.lock <mycmd> <args>
```

The `flock` command (f-lock) ensures that only one process can own the lock-file at once, and will sit and wait until it owns the lock-file before it launches the command you give it. As long as the sync and backup are launched in the right order then the backup will always wait until the sync is done.

The main gotcha is that you ever have a power-cut, network outage, or some other interruption the causes a stale lockfile to be leftover then you have to delete it manually before either job can ever run again (and if you don't notice quickly then there can be a whole bunch queued up).